# Symmetric Integral Matrices

Tags: nt.number-theory, matrices, modular-forms

Let $SM_n(R)$ be the set of $n\times n$ symmetric matrices with entries in a ring $R$ and let $A\sim B$ for such matrices if $A=C^T\cdot B\cdot C$ for some $C\in SL(n,R).$ It is an equivalence relation (appearing for example in the theory of modular forms, at least in the context of positive matrices).

Each $M\in SM_n(\mathbb Q)$ is equivalent to a diagonal matrix and that can be used  to classify all equivalence classes in $SM_n(\mathbb Q)$.

Is there a classification of $\sim$-equivalence classes in $SM_n(\mathbb Z)$? Or, at least, an algorithm for determination if $A\sim B$ for $A,B\in SM_n(\mathbb Z)$?

Comment: there is not much in the way of  reduced form for dimension 4 or larger. In Nipp's book of quaternary (positive) forms he explains that the reduced form he chose was somtimes a matter of taste. For ternary forms, Kap and I had tables from Schiemann, who had his own method of reduction. ...One preliminary comparison for positive forms is simply to count the number of representations of every $n < 20,$ say.  For indefinite it  gets worse:  the equivalence class of ternary forms coincides with the spinor genus.  See    http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/  . I like Cassels, Rational Quadratic Forms

Comment: http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/

Comment: @WillJagy: Many thanks! What's the relation between symmetric matrices up to the above equivalence and lattices though? (I am not an expert in these topics.)

Comment: I have never seen SM for symmetric matrices.  Sym is pretty common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer:

Let $M$ be an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix over a PID $R$. Then using an algorithm resembling the one for computing Smith Normal Forms, we get that $M \sim E\oplus\bigoplus_{i=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} D_{i}$, where $E$ is either $1 \times 1$ or $0 \times 0$, and each $D_i$ is $2 \times 2$ and symmetric. The operation "$\oplus$" means direct sum of matrices.

The above reduces your problem to the case of symmetric matrices which are block-diagonal with $1 \times 1$ and $2 \times 2$ blocks.